# Cannot search range

Tags: excel, search, text, numbers, vba

I am very new to VB. Trying to write a Macro to help my daily tasks. Been on this site quite a bit, helped me get this far. Still having an issue so thought I'd post my problem.

I need to search column A for a certain Word, then search column B for a certain number, then count and display in a cell values within a range.

So essentially if column A = "Word" And column B < 0 Then
Cell.value = Countif(ColumnC, Range)
Else
MsgBox = "nothing found"

See below. It works but for some reason I get all values writing ColumnC range, it doesn't read Column A "Word" or Column B..
Any comments will help.
Advance Cheers!!

```
Sub Word()

Dim i As Integer, HDIpctCompl As Single
   For i = 1 To 10000

    If Worksheets("1").Cells(i, 1) = "Word " And Worksheets("1").Cells(i, 2) < 0 Then
        Worksheets("1").Cells(2, 12).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Worksheets("1").Range("C:C"), ">=0.5", Worksheets("1").Range("C:C"), "<=0.599")

        Worksheets("1").Cells(3, 12).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Worksheets("1").Range("C:C"), ">=0.4", Worksheets("1").Range("C:C"), "<=0.499")

        Worksheets("1").Cells(4, 12).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Worksheets("1").Range("C:C"), ">=0.3", Worksheets("1").Range("C:C"), "<=0.399")

        Worksheets("1").Cells(5, 12).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Worksheets("1").Range("C:C"), ">=0.2", Worksheets("1").Range("C:C"), "<=0.299")

        Worksheets("1").Cells(6, 12).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Worksheets("1").Range("C:C"), ">=0.1", Worksheets("1").Range("C:C"), "<=0.199")

HDIpctCompl = i     'Progress bar, works, different Sub
HDIprogress HDIpctCompl

    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

I have also been messing around with something below

```
Sub Word()

Dim i As Long, wb As Workbook, sh1 As Worksheet, ClmA As Range, Find As     Range, FindB As Range, ClmB As Range
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set sh1 = wb.Sheets("1")
Set ClmA = sh1.Range("A1:A10000")
Set ClmB = sh1.Range("B1:B10000")
Set Find = ClmA.Find("Word")
Set FindB = ClmB.Find("< 0 ")

For i = 1 To 10000
If Find = 0 And FindB = 1 Then

Else
            sh1.Cells(2, 7).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(sh1.Range("C:C"), ">=0.4", sh1.Range("C:C"), "<=0.499")
            sh1.Cells(3, 7).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(sh1.Range("C:C"), ">=0.3", sh1.Range("C:C"), "<=0.399")
            sh1.Cells(4, 7).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(sh1.Range("C:C"), ">=0.2", sh1.Range("C:C"), "<=0.299")
            sh1.Cells(5, 7).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(sh1.Range("C:C"), ">=0.1", sh1.Range("C:C"), "<=0.199")
            sh1.Cells(6, 7).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(sh1.Range("C:C"), ">=0.0", sh1.Range("C:C"), "<=0.099")

    If Find = 1 And FindB = 0 Then

    Else
 MsgBox "No information detected", vbOKOnly    
    Exit Sub       
    VIApctCompl = i
    Viaprogress VIApctCompl
   End If
  End If
 Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Your first code is looking at Column A and Column B in rows 1 to 10000 and then writing information to rows 2-6 in Column L if the correct information is found. Is this what you intended? There is no variable after `Then` so it will just keep replacing the values in rows 2-6 in Column L each time the criteria are met.

Comment: Yes, search for a certain word in column a, then if true search for numbers less than 0 then if true count and write in column L

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Sub Word()

With Worksheets("1")
.Cells(2, 12).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range("A:A"), "Word", .Range("B:B"), "<0", .Range("C:C"), ">=0.5", .Range("C:C"), "<=0.599")
.Cells(3, 12).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range   ("A:A"), "Word", .Range("B:B"), "<0", .Range("C:C"), ">=0.4", .Range("C:C"), "<=0.499")
.Cells(4, 12).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range("A:A"), "Word", .Range("B:B"), "<0", .Range("C:C"), ">=0.3", .Range("C:C"), "<=0.399")
.Cells(5, 12).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range("A:A"), "Word", .Range("B:B"), "<0", .Range("C:C"), ">=0.2", .Range("C:C"), "<=0.299")
.Cells(6, 12).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range("A:A"), "Word", .Range("B:B"), "<0", .Range("C:C"), ">=0.1", .Range("C:C"), "<=0.199")
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add more conditions to your `COUNTIFS` statement:

```
Sub Word()

With Worksheets("1")
    .Cells(2, 12).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range("A:A"), "Word", .Range("B:B"), "<0", .Range("C:C"), ">=0.5", .Range("C:C"), "<=0.599")
    .Cells(3, 12).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range("A:A"), "Word", .Range("B:B"), "<0", .Range("C:C"), ">=0.4", .Range("C:C"), "<=0.499")
    .Cells(4, 12).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range("A:A"), "Word", .Range("B:B"), "<0", .Range("C:C"), ">=0.3", .Range("C:C"), "<=0.399")
    .Cells(5, 12).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range("A:A"), "Word", .Range("B:B"), "<0", .Range("C:C"), ">=0.2", .Range("C:C"), "<=0.299")
    .Cells(6, 12).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range("A:A"), "Word", .Range("B:B"), "<0", .Range("C:C"), ">=0.1", .Range("C:C"), "<=0.199")
End With

End Sub
```

This will essentially eliminate the need for a progress bar because it should fill these in in no time.

Or if you want to simplify your code and make it easier to modify in the future, use the following:

```
Sub Word()

Dim i As Long, j As Long
With Worksheets("1")
    j = 2
    For i = 5 To 1 Step -1
        .Cells(j, 12).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range("A:A"), "Word", .Range("B:B"), "<0", .Range("C:C"), ">=0." & i, .Range("C:C"), "<=0." & i & "99")
        j = j + 1
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: CountIfs is searching for a range, between 01.1 and 0.199. I think the problem is when I am performing my .find in range A and Range B, it completely disregards that line and move right to countifs.                                                                                           Essentially I need a case, if, or for statement that will find a word in column A and the results from that find will then search column B for all numbers < 0 then once that statement is true, it countifs for column C.. Ive been palying around with the code and searching for solutions but works been piling up.

Comment: @User123 Your code is looping through 10000 rows of data, looking at the data in Column A and Column B, and then overwriting the data in Column L on every loop based on a CountIf on Column C. If you just want to count the total number of cells in Column C that are between a given value when the values in Column A and Column B meet a certain criteria, my code will work. Could you perhaps share a sample workbook with typical data?

Comment: Been busy so apologize for the late response. Thank you for your help. It appears, as usual, I was thinking too much into it and complicated it beyond repair lol. Ive tested it and it appears to be working. Removed the progress bar to clean up the module. Used the first code cause I quickly understood it and time is essential for this. Ill work on the second code for my case to clean it up. Ill let you all know if I have any problems. Again Thanks!!

Comment: Glad I could help! If this solved your problem, please mark the answer as correct.